# How do I set tmux's window size in a session started by cron?

Tags: cron, tmux

In my crontab, I reference a shell script, `print-size`, that contains the following lines.

```
#!/bin/sh
tmux new-session -t check-size -d
tmux send-keys -t check-size 'echo $COLUMNS $LINES' C-m
```

When this script executes as a cron job, it prints `80 23`, apparently because the default terminal size is 80x24.  If I execute this shell script from a terminal window, it prints the size of that terminal window (minus one line for tmux's status line).

Is there a way to influence the size of the tmux window so the above script will print something different, say `132 42`, in a cron job?

If it matters, this is for Ubuntu 14.04 but I suspect the same behavior in any *nix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the source code is the way to go: `tmux` only looks at the system's notion of the size in `check-size`, and before that, when attaching to or creating a session, it starts with 24x80.  The latter is configurable with the command-line `-x` and `-y` options.

The [manual page](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1) lists this in `new-session`:

> The new session is attached to the current terminal unless **`-d`** is given. window-name and shell-command are the name of and shell command to execute in the initial window. If **`-d`** is used, **`-x`** and **`-y`** specify the size of the initial window (80 by 24 if not given).

Comment: Yes, that's it, thank you. I was trying to set it after the fact with `resize-pane` which doesn't work since a pane cannot be larger than its enclosing window.